# Use css to create form rows with (minimally) auto sized labels and flexible input fields

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to create a simple form row that has the following 3 properties.

- allow for multiple labels and inputs on a single line
- labels are automatically sized to fit their text
- inputs flex to fill the remaining space

I have the following css:

```
.fill-field {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.fill-field label {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1%;
    padding: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.fill-field input {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

and it works nicely on the following html:

```
<div class="fill-field">
    <label>My name is</label><input placeholder="name"/>
    <label>I live in</label><input placeholder="city"/>
</div>
```

However for some reason if my input does not have a label

```
<div class="fill-field">
    <label>My name is</label><input placeholder="name"/>
    <label>I live in</label><input placeholder="city"/>
    <input placeholder="state"/>
</div>
```

or I try to specifically give an input a width:

```
<style>
    input.year {
        width: 40px;
    }
</style>
<div class="fill-field">
    <label>My name is</label><input placeholder="name"/>
    <label>I was born in</label><input class="year" placeholder="year"/>
</div>
```

The desired effect is lost.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/FoxMulder900/zyfccw7L/), any ideas on how to make my css handle all 3 layout examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This flexbox CSS may meet all your criteria:

```
.fill-field {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.fill-field label {
  padding: 5px;
}

.fill-field input {
  flex: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/dnc3h0k4/)

Here's the extra css needed for the 3rd example that has an input with an explicit width:

```
input.year {
  width: 40px;
  flex: none;
}
```

Comment: Works great and is cleaner than what I had! The only addition I had to make was to add flex:none to any input which I wanted to set the width explicitly. (I'll edit your answer to include it)

Comment: I now see that your edit was rejected.  I've added it.

Comment: No idea, but it definitely improves the answer, so I'm happy to include it.